# Showing the description on mouseover

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to display the content in the description column in the table when the mouse is hovered on top of the name attribute in the table. This is the model class.

I have a table which has columns name, type and description. I need to use the column description as my hover text in my Index View.

```
public class mouseover
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<description.Models.mouseover>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.type)
    </th>
    @*<th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.description)
    </th>*@
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.type)
    </td>
    @*<td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.description)
    </td>*@
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: What table? Where's the view code?

Comment: @Alberto : added the view code. the table is created only for learning purpose. And so doesn't have anything to do.

Comment: try to use jquery scripts for that purpose. put some class for the td and set it visible on mouse over event

Comment: I am not sure about using Jquery. But can the code be reused for all mouseover views in my program?

Comment: that depends on your functionality.

Comment: I will add the Jquery in my curret View and try if it works.

Comment: yes that would be better.

Comment: Have you tried this syntax @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name, new { title=model.name } )

Comment: You can use either "bootstrap tooltip" or "jquery.ui tooltip". Another option - is qTip javascript plugin. Also there is an opportunity to write your own script that will show a simple div when you hover description element. If you are interesting - I can show you how.

Here are links to listed above plugins:
1. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/
2. https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use HTML `title` global attribute but why don't you use Boostrap tooltip to achieve your goal?

[Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e7cm4rgs/): it has a simple table with one row and column, as example for your table.

```
<td data-toggle="tooltip" title="Description" data-placement="right">
    Name
</td>
```

As you can see you just need to change Name and Description with `@item.name` and `@item.description`.
You have also to enable tooltips:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
})
```

Remember to include all needed css and js files of course jQuery and Bootstrap:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Let me know if this was useful.

Comment: Yeah it worked perfectly. But i have not added any of these files in the current html file nor the Jquery in the fiddle.

Comment: Is it really necessary to use bootstrap to show the title in tool tip? Adding a title to td appears to be showing the tool tip : <td  title="Description" > . I agree that using bootstrap would provide lot more features such as data-placement, but is that really necessary to show the tool tip on hover?

Comment: Webcodervk, please look at my last comment for the main post.

Comment: @webcodervk you are right: title (a global attribute) is there to provide more information and browsers display them in a popup. Since this is HTML ABC I wanted to provide a more customizable and flexible alternative to Vini Vasundharan.

Comment: So is it necessary that i add everything in the fiddle when it works perfectly without any of then?

Comment: If you want a simple, non-customizable, browser dependent tooltip then you can just use title attribute. If you want to customize it then you should go with other options, I provided one of those.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the links and answer. it helped me. It can be used in textbox as well right?